# Can I customize the "New File" menu in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, customization

I would like to add some other options, like "PHP Enum" or "PHP Interface" directly to this menu. Also, I would like to put PHP-related options first. It is possible tu customize this in PhpStorm? I'm using last version (2022.3.2) with the new UI enabled.

I tried using `Appearance & Behaviour -> Menus & Toolbars` but that didn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4407241310738-How-to-Add-a-New-File-Type-to-the-New-Dialogue

Comment: 1) Do you know that you can use the universal "PHP Class" entry and just change the type of the object (and therefore the file template) there? That can be done right when typing the file or class name -- just use `Arrow Up/Down` keys. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-php-classes.html

Comment: 2) You can add new entries to that menu by adding custom File Templates and they will appear in that menu: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-file-and-code-templates.html

Comment: 3) As for customizing this menu (removing items, changing their order) -- not possible at the moment. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143090 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know that you can use the universal **PHP Class** entry and just change the type of the object (and therefore the file template) there? That can be done right away when typing the file or class name -- just use <kbd>Arrow Up / Down</kbd> keys:

[image]
*(GREEN rectangle area is where that <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> key will work; RED rectangle shows my custom file templates)*

**P.S.** The template for `PHP Enums` is also there, it just the screenshot was taken in a project with PHP 8.0 language level (need 8.1 for enums to appear).

**P.P.S.** The IDE will remember the last used template when you invoke this dialog again.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-php-classes.html

---

**You can add new entries to this menu** by creating custom File Templates at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates`
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-file-and-code-templates.html

Here are my test custom file templates:

[image]

And this is how they appear in that menu:

[image]

---

**Customizing this menu** (removing items, changing their order)

This is not possible at the moment. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143090 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.